# Three columns A B C, take A*B while cumsum is less than 10 then take A*C

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have the following dataframe

```
A   B   C   
5   1   0.7 
7   1   0.7
-1  1   0.7 
-3  1   0.7 
12  1   0.7
```

I'd like to multiply A and B or A and C based on a the cumulative sum of previous multiplications.

First iteration, the cum sum is 0 so we shall multiply A and B thus get

```
A   B   C   cum sum
5   1   0.7    5
7   1   0.7 
-1  1   0.7 
-3  1   0.7 
12  1   0.7
```

cum sum is less than 10 so we shall again multiply A and B, thus get

```
A   B   C   cum sum
5   1   0.7 5
7   1   0.7 12
-1  1   0.7 
-3  1   0.7 
12  1   0.7
```

Now the cum sum is larger than 10 and thus we shall multiply A and C and thus get

```
A   B   C   cum sum
5   1   0.7 5
7   1   0.7 12
-1  1   0.7 11.3
-3  1   0.7 
12  1   0.7
```

Continuing this the expected output would be

```
A   B   C   cum sum
5   1   0.7 5
7   1   0.7 12
-1  1   0.7 11.3
-3  1   0.7 9.2
12  1   0.7 21.2
```

```
a = {'A':[5, 7, -1, -3, 12]}
b = {'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
c = {'C' : [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7]}

a.update(b)
a.update(c)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are the commas supposed to be decimal points?

Comment: Yes, let me change that @not_speshal

Comment: you may need create the for loop

Comment: Shouldn't the last two rows b2 9.2 and 21.2?

Comment: So when we drop back below 10 we switch back to A * B?

Comment: Will the B and C columns always be constants?

Comment: yes correct, my mistake @not_speshal

Comment: @KyleParsons yes correct. When we drop below 10 we switch back to A * B, and if we were to go above 10 again we go A * C

Comment: The column B will always be constant, C might change @KyleParsons

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop would work

```
cs = [0]
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if cs[-1] > 10:
        curr = cs[-1] + row.A * row.C
    else:
        curr = cs[-1] + row.A * row.B
    cs += [curr]

pandas.Series(cs[1:])

# 0     5.0
# 1    12.0
# 2    11.3
# 3     9.2
# 4    21.2
# dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using a `for` loop but instead iterating over a list of values of A with a custom function:

```
def filtered_cumsum(a, factor=0.7):
    result = [a[0]]
    for num in a[1:]:
        result.append(result[-1]+num*(1 if result[-1]<10 else factor))
    return result

df["cumsum"] = filtered_cumsum(df["A"].tolist())

>>> df
     A  cumsum
0    5     5.0
1    7    12.0
2   -1    11.3
3   -3     9.2
4   12    21.2
5  -78   -33.4
6  -98  -131.4
7   91   -40.4
8   32    -8.4
9   -7   -15.4
10  37    21.6
11  70    70.6
```